# How to pass a variable space character in tr command

Tags: bash, shell, unix, replace

In a shell script I would like to replace all underscore characters with a blank space in a function that use tr but a receive an error because I don't know of to pass a space in a variable to tr

```
function sanitizeDirName() {
  local name=$1
  local f=$2
  local r=$3
  echo ${name##*/} | grep -E -o $re | tr $f $r 
}

sanitizeDirName "~/test_1" "_" " "
```

Thank you

Comment: `echo ${name##*/} | grep -E -o "$re" | tr "$f" "$r"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote your variables, since they are populated from user input and could have whitespaces or metacharacters (as tripleee pointed out in the comments):

```
echo ${name##*/} | grep -E -o "$re" | tr "$f" "$r"
```

If you want to remove `_` then you might want to use the `-d` flag

```
echo ${name##*/} | grep -E -o $re | tr -d $f
```

Comment: It works thanks :-)
And what if I want to replace _  at all ?
Like this
sanitizeDirName "~/test_1" "_" ""
If I try i receive this error : tr: empty string2

Comment: Actually you should quote *everything* in there.  If `$name` contains any shell metacharacters or irregular whitespace, echoing it unquoted will change it.  If the regular expression contains any shell metacharacters or whitespace, the `grep' will not work correctly.  If `$f` contains any shell metacharacters or whitespace, the `tr` command will not work correctly.

Comment: Yes since we are dealing with user input, you are right. I just highlighted what was the problem is his code. I will update my answer though.